# Fresh Install and partitioning Problem and Doubts

Tags: partitioning

I have two questions:

1. I Have a fresh install of ubuntu and in Gparted I have the information of having:

   > `/dev/sda1   ext2   /boot   243mb   49.22mb used`
   >
   > `/dev/sda2  extended       595.93 GiB`
   >
   > `/dev/sda5 crypt-luks   595.93 GiB`

   This last line has a "!" mark that says: "Linux Unified Key Setup Encryption is not yet supported". `sda5` is accopolated to `sda2` as if we are talking about the same partition, in fact my hard drive has 600GB.

   So is there any problem with the partition configuration and with the clean install of my Ubuntu? It is like it should be? Because I had a lot of problems with formatting and partitions.
2. Should I keep it like this or format again and create partition for swap, boot and home like I see everyone talking about? It would be better for the PC?

Don't know if you need this information but I have 6GB of RAM, and a i7 processor on a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks perfectly normal. You probably don't even need swap with 6Gb of RAM unless you simulate nuclear reactions on your laptop.

So, as they said in that ad, *you can* reinstall your system with swap and separate `/home` partition *if you want to*, but if you *don't want to* then you *don't have to*. :)

Regarding the `sda5` being "inside" `sda2`: the latter is an extended partition - due to limitations of MBR partitioning scheme hard drive can contain at most 4 "primary" partitions. To overcome this restriction, an "extended" partition may be created which acts as a container for more partitions. This is absolutely normal.

Regarding "not yet supported": I suppose this means crypt-luks partitions are not yet fully supported by gparted (maybe they can't be resized or something like that). I understand that you can boot your system, so indeed it IS supported by the OS.

Comment: hey! thank you for you answer =)
alright then, and what about sda5 and "Linux Unified Key Setup Encryption is not yet supported"
no stress either?

Comment: @GonçaloGaspar: I updated the answer

Comment: If the partitions were wrong, the system would not run.  Using the guided automatic partition setup is a very good strategy in 99.99% of cases.

Comment: Alright!! Thanks everyone for their time and answers!!!

Comment: *"unless you simulate nuclear reactions on your laptop"* :D